# How to configure Apache2 and PHP-FPM to run two versions of PHP in different directories

Tags: php, apache2

I've been searching for information how to run two versions of PHP using Apache2.4.38 and PHP-FPM on Debian 10.4.

I want to achieve result like that:

- website.com - run on php5.6
- website.com/php74 - run on php7.4

I have installed and was doing everything like in that tutorial : [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-debian-10)

We are trying to test some new frameworks, and we can't update the php versions.
In that tutorial is the configuration for two different sites(on one server), I would like to make it on one site, and php version depends on which directory we are currently.

Thanks for any advice posted in this question :)

**SOLVED**

```
<Location "/foldername">
    #  SetHandler etc.....
</Location>
```

Omg, I don't even know why I didn't use that.
Thanks!

CzukER

Comment: Can you just use an inner `<Location "/php74">` directive with a different `SetHandler`?